# UILabel not showing centre align in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel

I am having one problem stuck. I have created UILabel and changed it frame i.e size height as per the content and it is very fine with all the iPhone devices. However my label is not centre align if we are getting just few word, like Adidas, Nike etc.

```
brandtitlelabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
brandtitlelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
brandtitlelabel.textColor = [UIColor commonTextColor];
brandtitlelabel.numberOfLines = 0;
brandtitlelabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
brandtitlelabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1;
brandtitlelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
brandtitlelabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
brandtitlelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:30];

NSString *text = @"Adidas";
NSAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:brandtitlelabel.font}];
rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){self.view.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX} options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
rect.origin = CGPointMake(0, 66);
brandtitlelabel.frame = rect;
brandtitlelabel.text = text;
[self.view addSubview:brandtitlelabel];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this.

```
brandtitlelabel.text = text;
brandtitlelabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x,brandtitlelabel.center.y);//replace an 'self.view' with your 'superver' on which you want to center.
[self.view addSubview:brandtitlelabel];
```

Comment: try and look. it will center of you whole view both x and y axis

Comment: if you want this you can do as you requirment.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line of code at the end after setting the frame.

```
brandtitlelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
brandtitlelabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work, i have tried that previously.